# Angular - Embedded PDF

Tags: angular

We do have an angular application where the user are allowed to upload PDF file. The issue is:- We should not allow user to upload any PDF with javascript embedded in it.

For example:- We can add an open action to a PDF, which shows a pop-up on file open. Now when the user uploads this file, Is there any way to identify a JS has been embedded and we need to reject it.

Can this be done through angular? If, Could you please instruct on how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Angular itself doesn't offer much in the way of PDF support, so you're asking about how to do this in javascript.  I believe you can use `pdf.js` https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js which has a `getJSActions` function which I believe does what you want https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L934